# JavaScript Logic App action error "Parsing code failed. Unexpected token ...'.'."

Tags: javascript, azure-logic-apps

(These are just a dummy datasets. Real datasets are big, and have 900 records in each datasets) I have two array datasets in my Logic App:

Dataset1:

```
[
    {
        "userId": "123",
        "name": "Victor"
    },
    {
        "userId": "456",
        "name": "Jack"
    },
    {
        "userId": "789",
        "name": "Winston"
    }
]
```

Datset2:

```
[
    {
        "userId": "123",
        "age": "75"
    },
    {
        "userId": "456",
        "age": "72"
    }
]
```

I want to apply a left join in Logic App and generate a final output:

```
    {
        "userId": "123",
        "name": "Victor",
        "age": "75"
    },
    {
        "userId": "456",
        "name": "Jack",
        "age": "72"
    },
    {
        "userId": "789",
        "name": "Winston",
        "age": null
    }
]
```

First I applied a For Each loop and condition using native Logic App actions, which works fine but since the datasets are large, it takes around 3 hours to complete. So I applied a below Inline JavaScript code in Logic App.

```
const dataset1 = [
    {
        "userId": "123",
        "name": "Victor"
    },
    {
        "userId": "456",
        "name": "Jack"
    },
    {
        "userId": "789",
        "name": "Winston"
    }
]

const dataset2 = [
    {
        "userId": "123",
        "age": "75"
    },
    {
        "userId": "456",
        "age": "72"
    }
]

const output = dataset1.map(x => {
    const result = dataset2.find(element => element.userId === x.userId);
    return {...x, age: result?.age || null};
})

console.log(output)
```

When I run this code outside of Logic App, it works fine but when I run it from the inside the Logic App JavaScript action, it does not let me save the Logic App and throws below error:

[image]

Failed to save logic app logic-test. 'The input parameter 'code' for inline code action 'Execute_JavaScript_Code' contains invalid code. Parsing the code failed with error 'Line 29: **Unexpected token ...'.'**. Status code: 'BadRequest'.

Comment: Looks like you might have to use `age: result ? result.age || null` instead

Comment: `result ? (result.age || null) : null` seems like your environment doesn't support modern syntax

Comment: @ChrisG tried return {...x, age: result ? result.age || null}; it still gives Unexpected token ...'.'

Comment: @KonradLinkowski also tried return {...x, age: result ? (result.age || null) : null}; and same error Unexpected token ...'.'

Comment: `...`  is also a new syntax, you have to  use `Object.assign`

Comment: @KonradLinkowski Sorry I am not a JavaScript developer, can you please help me with the syntax

Comment: Look up [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) and try it yourself.

Comment: Worked out my way. Thanks for the prompt responses and the push both of you. :-)

return Object.assign(x, {age: result ? (result.age || null) : null});

Answer (score 0):

i think you just forget parenthesis in you inline function

```
 const output = dataset1.map((x) => {
 const result = dataset2.find((element) => element.userId === x.userId);
 return { ...x, age: result?.age || null };
 });
```

result:

[image]

Comment: Tried your code, it still throws the same error. Unexpected token ...'.'

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
return result === undefined ? { ...x, age: "null" } : { ...x, ...result };
```

but dont give me a negative point i'm trying to help

Comment: I understand, I'm here to recieve any help. I didn't give any negative point btw.

Anway, just tried your code and it still threw the same error.

I think ChrisG and KonradLinkowski are right. LogicApp envirinment doesn't support modern JavaScript. I tried this and it worked fine: return Object.assign(x, {age: result ? (result.age || null) : null});